# SingleNodeIntegrationTestSupport and jobs

Tags: java, spring-xd

Is there a reason why `org.springframework.xd.dirt.test.SingleNodeIntegrationTestSupport` is not providing methods for job testing?

Job module integration tests in Spring XD project are carried with a different tools e.g. `org.springframework.xd.integration.test.AbstractJobTest` which copies all the files into a running Spring XD container (`copyJobToCluster` method).

Are there technical reasons why it's not possible to start up embedded Spring XD for job testing e.g. class loader setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any technical reason why you couldn't run an embedded container to test a job. For stream testing, XD provides test fixtures that make it easy to send a message to a stream and receive and verify the result. Processing a single message in a stream is expected to happen "fast", and verifying the resulting payload from a source, processor (or processing chain) is fairly straightforward. Testing a sink requires more work to verify the state of whatever external resource is bound to it. These characteristics make stream testing practical for a unit integration test. On the other hand, a batch job can run for an arbitrarily long time which is not necessarily a good fit for Junit IMHO. Technically, there may be some boilerplate code to trigger a job, and detect when a job is complete and such things could be supported by the testing framework. I'm not sure what can be done beyond that.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer. For now I'll try to use `JobDeployer` in the same way `StreamDeployer` is used in `SingleNodeIntegrationTestSupport`.

Do you have any plans to make `AbstractJobTest` a part of `spring-xd-dirt` or `spring-xd-integration-test` libraries so people can you use it for their own tests?